# R- How write a loop for applying a function built-in already in a a package to all columns of a df and populate another df?

Tags: r

So far I splitted the df in df contained in a list as I want to do this operation for each different sample.

```
TestData <- split(df, df$SAMPLE)
output_Data <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(TestData)){
  
  TestData[[i]] <- TestData[[i]] %>%
    select(contains("strings")) ###subset columns I need to apply the function on
  
}
```

Comment: something like `sapply(TestData, function(i) select(i, contains('strings')))`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
library(purrr)

(data <- df %>%
         split(.$SAMPLE) %>%
         map(~ select(.x, contains("strings"))))
```

This approach is closer to R philosophy of functional programming and compliant with the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) style of doing things.